# What is the most neutral word for "shield"?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request

As you know, Latin language has several terms for what we call "shield", namely *clipeus*, *scutum*, *parma*, *pelta* etc. I'm just wondering which among them is the most "neutral" or "common" word that referring "shields", or is there perhaps a blanket term for them?

I am looking for a Classical word (if any) for "a hand-carried armor designed for battle", or metaphoric usage of it that translates English "shield" such as in ["Religious Liberty Is a Shield and Not a Sword"](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/harry-knox/post_9703_b_7702140.html). I'm also interested in knowing if Latin since the Classical period would use the same word or a different one, because I have little knowledge about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***[Clipeus](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=clipeus&filter=CUTF8)*** was originally a round, metal shield. It is [fairly common](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=clipeo).

***[Scutum](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=scutum&filter=CUTF8)*** was originally a long, oval wooden shield with iron fittings and covered with leather, used by soldiers. It is also used for a shield in general. It is [about as common](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=scuto) as *clipeus*.

Both words were also used metaphorically for a defence or protection in general.

Comment: _Tutamen_ would also be suitable — as a blanket term as requested, perhaps even better.

Answer (score 6):

Just to supplement…

If you want a very highbrow, poetic term, you can borrow the Greek ***aegis, aegidis, f***. See, for example, Ovid's *Remedia Amoris* 343-6, where he recommends distracting attention from any unflattering physical features with jewelry:

> Auferimur cultu; gemmis auroque teguntur
>     Omnia; pars minima est ipsa puella sui.
> Saepe ubi sit, quod ames, inter tam multa requiras;
>     Decipit hac oculos **aegide** dives Amor.
>
> *We men are won over by splendor: jewels and gold can hide everything else. A girl is really the least part of herself. Often you might ask, what is there really to love, underneath all that? But **with this shield** of wealth, Cupid can trick the eyes.*

In the comments, Tom Cotton also recommends ***tūtāmen, tūtāminis, n***. This is a nice general-purpose word for *defense* or *protection*: anything that keeps you safe against attack. So I'd say it's exactly the opposite of *aegis*, a simple, straightforward term instead of a lofty metaphor. L&S's example for it comes from Aeneid 5.258-62, describing a prize given at the funeral games:

> at qui deinde locum tenuit virtute secundum,
> levibus huic hamis consertam auroque trilicem
> loricam, quam Demoleo detraxerat ipse
> victor apud rapidum Simoenta sub Ilio alto,
> donat habere, viro decus et **tutamen** in armis.
>
> *And as for the man who came in second place, Aeneas gave him a shirt of chainmail, bound together with polished rings and triple-reinforced with pure gold, that he [Aeneas] himself had ripped off of Demoleus after defeating him under the high walls of Troy, on the banks of the river Simois—it was both a mark of glory, and **a useful defense** against weapons.*

Finally, ***tegāmen, tegāminis, n*** is another word for "protection", from the same root as English *protect*. But while the other words refer to armor, this one refers to a cloak, and can mean "concealment" as well. Metaphorically, Cicero uses it to mean a solid defense against accusations and implications. It's less common than the other two, but would be just as easily understood by a classical Roman.